# Publish local GIT repo to TFS

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I've been following the tutorial here : http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-code-in-git-vs.aspx to try and use our local GIT repo as the source control for TFS.

In that tutorial, there is an option to "Publish your repository into your team project". But in my VS 2013 Express (and Ultimate) there is no such option.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you connect (http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/connect-to-vs#connectvs) your project to a TFS *git* repo?

Comment: Yes, we created a blank TFS Git project in Visual Studio Online. I've also tried copying the contents of my local /MyProj/.git/ folder to the cloned TFS Git repo folder, but it doesn't work.

My colleague has just got it to work! Will post his solution in a few minutes.

Comment: He actually forgot the steps that he'd done to get it to work, and we can't seem to work it out again.

Answer (score 0):

Because you created the local repo, instead of cloning the one from Team Project? In that case you must set the TP URL as the remote repo of your local repo.

In other words Git must become aware of the relationship between repositories.

Comment: Yes we have a historical GIT repo that we've been using for ages and now want to move it to TFS. These are the steps I tried:
1) Connect to TFS in visual studio
2) Clone blank TFS GIT repor to new local repo
3) Right click on new local repo and open command prompt
4) run git pull /path/to/old/local/repo
5) run git remote rm origin
6) run git remote add origin https://oursite.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/OurProj
7) run git push -u origin --all